# Trying to Reverse Order of Images in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to reverse the order of images that are displayed. I'm a PHP noob and I'm not sure how to do it. I guess I need to reverse the order of foreach that is displayed, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that.

```
<div class="yacht-view-right">
<?php
if (count($tpl['gallery_arr']) > 0)
{
    $is_open = false;
    foreach ($tpl['gallery_arr'] as $k => $v)
    {

        if ($k == 0) 
        {
            $size = getimagesize(BASE_PATH . $v['medium_path']);
            ?>
            <p><?php print_r(array_keys($v));
                 print_r(array_VALUES($v));
                 echo (count($tpl['gallery_arr'])) 
                 ?></p>
<div class="yacht-view-pic" id="yacht-view-pic" style="width:<?php echo $size[0]; ?>px; height: <?php echo $size[1]; ?>px;"> 
<img id="yacht-view-medium-pic" src="<?php echo BASE_PATH . $v['medium_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($v['title'])); ?>"/> </a>
</div>
<?php
        }h

        $is_open = true;
        ?>
<div class="yacht-view-img">
<a href="<?php echo BASE_PATH . $v['large_path']; ?>" data-lightbox="yachts">
<img src="<?php echo BASE_PATH . $v['small_path']; ?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($v['title'])); ?>" />
</a>
</div>


<?php
        /*if ($k > 0 && ($k + 1) % 4 === 0)
        {
            $is_open = false;
            ?><div class="clear_left"></div><?php
        }*/
    }

    if ($is_open)
    {
        ?>
<div class="clear_left"></div>
<?php
    }
} else {

}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028273/reverse-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) before starting your `foreach` iteration:

```
$is_open = false;
$tpl['gallery_arr'] = array_reverse( $tpl['gallery_arr'], true );
foreach ($tpl['gallery_arr'] as $k => $v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reverse the order of the array using [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) before iterating through it with foreach:

```
foreach ( array_reverse( $tpl['gallery_arr'] ) as $k => $v)
```

or you could iterate in reverse using a counter (which may have slightly better performance, if the array is large):

```
$gallery = $tpl['gallery_arr'];
for($i = $first = count($gallery) - 1; $i >= 0; $i-- ) {
    $v = $gallery[$i];

    if ( $k == $first ) {
        ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you could use the `array_reverse()` function

```
$tpl['gallery_arr'] = array_reverse( $tpl['gallery_arr'], true );
foreach ($tpl['gallery_arr'] as $k => $v){
...
}
```

Or use a regular `for` loop with inverted parameters.

```
for($k = count($tpl['gallery_arr']) - 1; $k >= 0; $k--){
$v = $tpl['gallery_arr'][$k];
...
}
```