# Re-order a PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array with data. I'm currently displaying it from my foreach loop as provided, but I want to reorder it (Starting from the MAX id to MIN id)

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 18:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 19:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457544494
    [timestamp_end] => 1457548094
    [orders] => 1
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 2
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 17:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 18:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457540894
    [timestamp_end] => 1457544494
    [orders] => 0
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 3
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 16:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 17:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457537294
    [timestamp_end] => 1457540894
    [orders] => 0
    )
[3] => Array (
    [id] => 4
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 15:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 16:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457533694
    [timestamp_end] => 1457537294
    [orders] => 0
    )
[4] => Array (
    [id] => 5
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 14:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 15:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457530094
    [timestamp_end] => 1457533694
    [orders] => 0
    )
[5] => Array (
    [id] => 6
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 13:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 14:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457526494
    [timestamp_end] => 1457530094
    [orders] => 0
    )
[6] => Array (
    [id] => 7
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 12:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 13:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457522894
    [timestamp_end] => 1457526494
    [orders] => 0
    )
[7] => Array (
    [id] => 8
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 11:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 12:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457519294
    [timestamp_end] => 1457522894
    [orders] => 0
    )
[8] => Array (
    [id] => 9
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 10:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 11:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457515694
    [timestamp_end] => 1457519294
    [orders] => 0
    )
[9] => Array (
    [id] => 10
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 09:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 10:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457512094
    [timestamp_end] => 1457515694
    [orders] => 0
    )
[10] => Array (
    [id] => 11
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 08:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 09:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457508494
    [timestamp_end] => 1457512094
    [orders] => 0
    )
[11] => Array (
    [id] => 12
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 07:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 08:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457504894
    [timestamp_end] => 1457508494
    [orders] => 0
    )
[12] => Array (
    [id] => 13
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 06:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 07:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457501294
    [timestamp_end] => 1457504894
    [orders] => 0
    )
[13] => Array (
    [id] => 14
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 05:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 06:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457497694
    [timestamp_end] => 1457501294
    [orders] => 0
    )
[14] => Array (
    [id] => 15
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 04:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 05:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457494094
    [timestamp_end] => 1457497694
    [orders] => 0
    )
[15] => Array (
    [id] => 16
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 03:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 04:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457490494
    [timestamp_end] => 1457494094
    [orders] => 0
    )
[16] => Array (
    [id] => 17
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 02:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 03:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457486894
    [timestamp_end] => 1457490494
    [orders] => 0
    )
[17] => Array (
    [id] => 18
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 01:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 02:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457483294
    [timestamp_end] => 1457486894
    [orders] => 0
    )
[18] => Array (
    [id] => 19
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 00:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 01:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457479694
    [timestamp_end] => 1457483294
    [orders] => 0
    )
[19] => Array (
    [id] => 20
    [timestamp_start_ex] => Wed Mar  9 00:00:00 2016
    [timestamp_end_ex] => Wed Mar  9 00:28:14 2016
    [timestamp_start] => 1457478000
    [timestamp_end] => 1457479694
    [orders] => 0
    )
```

I would like to inverse the array, it means:

```
[0] => id = 19
[1] => id = 18
(...)
[19] => id => 1
```

I tried with `ksort()` but nothing, It does not want to reorganize the Array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028273/reverse-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`krsort()` will sort on the keys, which is not the same as the id.  Your example shows reordering the keys based on descending sort.

It would be best to do `ORDER BY id DESC` in your query, but for this simple example, since they are already in ascending order:

```
$array = array_reverse($array);
```

If not already sorted, then extract an array of `id` using `array_column()` and sort that descending while sorting `$array` by the same order:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'id'), SORT_DESC, $array);
```

Comment: `$array = array_reverse($array);` is working perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
function cmp($item1, $item2) {
    $a = intval($item1["id"]);
    $b = intval($item2["id"]);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: but OP says he wants it to be sorted by id, so `usort` would be best